# Group VM name and send into single email which having same email in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, vmware, powercli

I'm just getting started with powerCLI. Trying to write a script that get the vm name in CSV, check vm's guest disks with less than 20% free space and email to email address listed in CSV. However, I have difficult to group "name" into single email which having same email.

Below is the script that I use to list out vm's guest disks which less than 20%

```
import-csv ".\vm.csv"  | Group-Object $_."email"

ForEach ($VM in Get-VM $_."name" ){($VM.Extensiondata.Guest.Disk | `
Select @{N="Name";E={$VM.Name}},DiskPath, `
@{N="Capacity(MB)";E={[math]::Round($_.Capacity/ 1MB)}}, `
@{N="Free Space(MB)";E={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / 1MB)}} ,`
@{N="Free Space %";E={[math]::Round(((100* ($_.FreeSpace))/ ($_.Capacity)),0)}} | Where-Object {($_."Free Space %" -lt 20)})}
```

For example in CSV :

```
name   email    
vm1    test1@abc.com
vm2    test2@abc.com
vm3    test1@abc.com
vm4    test2@abc.com
```

Output:

```
email received by test1@abc.com
   No  VM    Free%
    1. vm1    10
    2. vm3     9

email received by test2@abc.com
   No  VM    Free%
    1. vm2     13
    2. vm4     15
```

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
Function SendSimpleMail 
{ 
             # Déclaration des paramètres 
             param([string]$Objet, [string]$Message, [string[]]$ToMail)

$SmtpServer="yoursmtpname"
$encoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$FromMail="from@domain"

Send-MailMessage -To $ToMail -Subject $Objet -Body $Message -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -From $FromMail -Encoding $encoding

}

import-csv ".\vm.csv"  | %{
$VM=Get-VM $_.name
$Email==$_.email
$VM.Extensiondata.Guest.Disk | %{
                                [pscustomobject]@{
                                Email=$Email
                                Name=$VM.Name
                                DiskPath=$_.DiskPath
                                "Capacity(MB)"=[math]::Round($_.Capacity/ 1MB)
                                "Free Space(MB)"=[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / 1MB)
                                "Free Space %"=if ($_.Capacity -eq 0) {0} else {[math]::Round(((100* ($_.FreeSpace))/ ($_.Capacity)),0)}
                                }
}

} | group Email | %{

$body=$_.group | Out-String
SendSimpleMail "subject" $body $_.Name

}
```

Comment: Hi Esperento57, thanks for your script. It shown error as below when I execute the script. `Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:18 char:33
+                                 [pscustomobject]@{
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
 `. Kindly advice.

Comment: May i know what is the "%" meant for and how can I make show in table format html?

Comment: Cool, it’s work. Can you show how to put the out string into table format ? I want put in table for easy viewing when come to long list.  I have tried many times , insert html , but only able to show one record in table. Appreciate if u could show.

Comment: In Send-MailMessage  add -BodyAsHtml and build your html for body variable. You can too try $body=$_.group | ConvertTo-Html

Comment: Its still same error, `Attempted to divide by zero.
At C:\Users\\Desktop\test.ps1:18 char:33
+                                 [pscustomobject]@{
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException`

Comment: I have added HTML for body variable, able to list in format table, but unable to list out the list of "No." for every row. Any method i can list it?